# facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo(); no longer working

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I've added the following in the xpages beforePageLoad to return the url path:

```
var url = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestPathInfo();
```

This was working in prior versions of Domino, but returns a null on my current 12.0.2 Domino server.

I'm accessing the facesContext in the beforePageLoad so that I can lookup the unid for the document to load prior to the xpage loading. Any ideas on why this is not working or a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `getRequestPathInfo()`to access the part between the .xsp and the query parameters (and not the file path including the .nsf itself). The documentation says: "*Return the extra path information (if any) included in the request URI; otherwise, return null.*"

So this will return null: `/folder/db.nsf/xpage.xsp`, while this will return "/test": `/folder/db.nsf/xpage.xsp/test`

You can use `facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath()` to get the folder/file path of the request.

---

If the unid is sent as a query parameter in the URL, you can do this to get hold of the unid value (assuming the parameter for the unid is called 'unid'):

```
var unid = param.get("unid");
```